# "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first" in remote SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I'm quite familiar with `MultipleActiveResultSets` but unfortunately, this one won't be enough this time !

I'm trying to run in **parallel** one SSIS package remotely in C#, hopefully I'm adding MARS into connectionstring but it doesn't prevent `ssis.Catalogs[catalog].Executions[executionIdentifier];` to generate the well known `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.` randomly.

```
var package = ssis.Catalogs[catalog]?.Folders[folder]?.Projects[project]?.Packages[packagename];
if(package != null)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            var parameters = new Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet>
            {
                new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet { ParameterName = "Success", ParameterValue = true, ObjectType = (short)SSISParameterLevel.Package },
                new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet { ParameterName = "LOGGING_LEVEL", ParameterValue = 3, ObjectType = (short)SSISParameterLevel.System }
            };

            var executionIdentifier = package.Execute(false, null, parameters);

            ExecutionOperation execution = null;
            try
            {
                // this one fails
                execution = ssis.Catalogs[catalog].Executions[executionIdentifier];
                do
                {
                    // if previous was failing, this one can fails as well
                    execution.Refresh();
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
                while (!execution.Completed);
            }catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
              //### getting randomly 'There is already an open DataReader ....'
            }
            Trace.TraceInformation($"{executionIdentifier}\t{execution.Status}");
        }
        );

        tasks.Add(task);
        task.Start();
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("all completed");
}
```

[image]

I suspect the `MARS` isn't really transmitted to the `IntegrationService` instance. Is there other way to enforce this behavior? or should I fall back querying myself some database for tracking SSIS package progress & completion state ?

Comment: How is your connection/data context defined, is it a property of a class, are you wrapping it with a using?

Comment: in the screenshot above, you can see the using.
and no extra fuzz except or wrapping, direct usage of assembly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices?view=sqlserver-2017

Comment: Ok, I see it now.